# Display number of rows and columns

Tags: vb.net

I have in my table MS Access named ( Table1 ) two fields ( ID1 - Team1 ).
With NumericUpDown1 i select the number of rows that i want to display after randomize in DataGridView2.With NumericUpDown2 i select the number of columns that i want to display after randomize in DataGridView2.If i choose with NumericUpDown2 only one column ( the number 1 ) it work very well with this query :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Con_randomize()
    Dim rows As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(NumericUpDown1.Value, rows) Then
        MsgBox("NUMBER NOT AVAILABLE", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        NumericUpDown1.Value = ""
        NumericUpDown1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If NumericUpDown2.Value = 1 Then
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT Top {0} ID1,Team1 From Table1 ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID1)*Time())", rows)
        InfoCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, Con_randomize)
        InfoAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
        InfoTable = New DataTable()
        InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = InfoTable
        DataGridView2.Columns(0).HeaderText = "NUMERO"
        DataGridView2.Columns(1).HeaderText = "CATEGORY1"
    End If
End Sub
```

How to make if i choose with NumericUpDown2 the number 2 or 3 columns i want to display in Datagridview2.
The columns will be named ( CATEGORY2 - CATEGORY3 ) . for example ( 1  Victor - David - Vincent ) ( 2  wiliam- George - Joseph ) ..in my only field named Team1 I have a hundred of the names

Comment: your select statement only has 2 columns...you dont need a database to create a blank datatable...what do you want the columns to be named...and what is NUMERO for (a row number)?...should it be a editable and does it need to be there at all?

Comment: the columns will be named ( CATEGORY2 - CATEGORY3 ) . for example ( 1  Victor - David - Vincent ) ( 2  wiliam- George - Joseph )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why you need a query to initialize the data, but give this a go.  It will automatically create the columns the way you need them.

```
' If NumericUpDown2.Value = 1 Then ' Comment This If Block Out

' Create the Teams String
Dim teamsString as New System.Text.StringBuilder("")
For i as Integer = 1 to Convert.ToInt32(NumericUpDown2.Value)
    teamsString.Append(", (SELECT Top 1 Team1 From Table1 ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID1)*Time())) as Category" + i.ToString())
Next

Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT Top {0} ID1" + teamsString.ToString() + " From Table1 ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID1)*Time())", rows)
InfoCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, Con_randomize)
InfoAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
InfoTable = New DataTable()
InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
DataGridView2.DataSource = InfoTable
DataGridView2.Columns(0).HeaderText = "NUMERO"

' Don't Need This, We Made It the Binding Name
' DataGridView2.Columns(1).HeaderText = "CATEGORY1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ctznkane525 for help.very nice of you.your code work very well to create the desired numbers of columns but always I have the same name in all rows like this for example in first or second row ( 1 Joseph Joseph Joseph ) ( 2 David David David ).This is a big error since I do not want to repeat names with all rows and columns

Comment: is your Team1 column a name?

Comment: Yes i have field ID1 of type numeric and field Team1 of type Texte

Comment: Thank you Ctznkane525 for help.Now i have an error when i click on Button1 ( Syntax error (missing operator) in expression '(SELECT Top 1 Team1 As CATEGORY From Table1 ORDER BY RND (- (100000 * ID1) * Time ())) 1' )

Comment: Modified it to as categoryi

Comment: My apologies master I made you tired.now all the names in my datagridview1 have the same names in the first row like this for example ( 1 David David David ) ( 12 David David David ) ( 17 David David David )